# How do I insert some value a certain number of times into a List<T>?

Tags: c#, list

Let's say I had this list:

```
Children = new List<Child>();
```

How do I insert/add `null` *n* times into `Children`?

(Background: In my data access layer I need to set total children which I am grabbing from database. Now, my presentation just need to access `Children.Count`. So I am planning to insert `null` objects to `Children`.)

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: Not on topic, but maybe you should call it "Children", not "Childs"? Also, is the type really List<Childs>, not List<Child>?

Comment: @Tormod, Thanks. The class names are fictitious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To answer your question:**

Using a `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<count;i++) list.Add(null);
```

**For your actual problem:**

I have come across a similar problem (I have a collection that automatically pages and reads the next X from the database). I just wrapped a list into an own implementation of `IList<T>` where I faked the `Count`. On accessing a specific row I check whether it is already fetched from the DB. You could do that too, then you don't need to add all those elements.

(Don't get me wrong, I don't suggest to hack your way around this, I just wanted to offer you an insight in a possible *extended* solution, that I would consider too broad to put here as answer)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other better way to pass total to presentation from Data-access?

Comment: @user960567: I added it to the answer since that is the most valueable part of my answer.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote please? This is the most efficient *and* helpful post.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I won't discuss my downvote, but I'll explain my reasoning behind it: It is obvious that the question OP is not yet an experienced programmer – using a loop is an obvious solution, after all. And because the OP is still not very experienced, I would expect from a good answer to not just point out the immediate solution, but also that having to "fake" the `Count` property for another code part suggests that *that* other part might be the real issue that should be fixed. Your answer instead suggests that hacks are OK. Not a good habit to get into for beginners IMO!

Comment: @PatrickHofman: As an aside, whether a post is *the* most efficient and helpful perhaps shouldn't be judged by its author. (Incidentally, Stack Exchange sites don't permit authors to vote for their own posts.)

Comment: I don't suggest a hack, I suggest a real solution, including explanation how to extend the 'hack', as you say, to a real solution.

Comment: @stakx: As an experienced C# user, I do know that my code solution is more efficient that the other answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Like I said, I won't discuss my downvote. We are *both* entitled to our own opinion.

Comment: @stakx: True, I just wanted to be understood. I updated the post to include your concern, but I don't expect you to do anything with it.

Answer (score 6):

Don't really know what the difficulty is here, but I thought I would give you another example:

```
Children = Enumerable.Repeat<Child>(null, 10).ToList();
```